# После "!" заменить все символы на "*"

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Ввести строку. Если в строке есть символ "**`!`**", то заменить все символы после первого "**`!`**" на символ "**`*`**". 
Если символа "**`!`**" нет в строке, то вывести об этом сообщение.

Подскажите, как заменить все символы после "**`!`**", а не один? (ничего на просторах интернета не нашла)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
line = 'Если в строке есть символ "!", то заменить все символы после первого "!" на символ "*"'
index = line.find("!")

if index == -1:
    print('Символа "!" нет в строке, вывести об этом сообщение.')
else:
    line = line[0:index+1] + "*" * len(line[index+1:])
    print(f'\nline = {line}')


line = 'Hello World'
index = line.find("!")

if index == -1:
    print('\nСимвола "!" нет в строке, вывести об этом сообщение.')
else:
    line = line[0:index+1] + "*" * len(line[index+1:])
    print(f'line = {line}')
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = input()
if "!" in a:
    x = a.index('!')
    for i in range(x, len(a) - 1):
        a = a[:i+1] + "*"
    print(a)
else:
    print('! Не найден')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Метод replace заменит все знаки стареы указанные знаки на новые.
В данном случае к введённой строке сразу применяется метод replace,меняя все знаки "!" на "*".Повторно указанный replace поменяет "*" обратно на "!",но только первый элемент.

```
    a = input('>').replace('!', '*').replace('*', '!', 1)
    if '!' not in a:
        print('! отсутствует')
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).